# Why am I getting "TypeError: rejectWithValue is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to implement `redux-toolkit` to my reactjs to fetch data from my api and store it in my database:

The error: `"TypeError: thunkAPI.rejectWithValue is not a function at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:859:21"`

initial state:

```js
const initialState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  isLoading: false,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: null
}
```

I have the following asynchronous thunk to get the token from my headers and get the current authenticated user:

```js
export const loadUser = createAsyncThunk('auth/loadUser', async(thunkAPI) => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
    setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
  }

  try {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/me');
    return res.data;
  } catch (error) {
    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
  }
})
```

And this is my login thunk:

```js
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk('auth/login', async ({ email, password }, {rejectWithValue, dispatch}) => {
  const body = { email, password };
  
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };
  
  try {
    const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/login', body, config);
  
    dispatch(loadUser(res.data));
    console.log(body)
    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    return rejectWithValue(err.response.data);
  }
});
```

Form some reason my login action is coming fulfilled with the correct data, and the `loadUser` comes rejected.

```
export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers:{},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(loadUser.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading =true;
      })
      .addCase(loadUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isAuthenticated = true;
        state.user = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(loadUser.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
      })
      .addCase(registerUser.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(registerUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.token = localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isAuthenticated = true;
        state.user = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(registerUser.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
      })
      .addCase(loginUser.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isAuthenticated = true;
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.user = action.payload;
        state.token = localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
      })
      .addCase(loginUser.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.user = null;
      })
  }
});

export const {  } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

And this is my login form:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { loginUser } from '../../slices/authSlice'
import './Register.css'

function Login() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ 
    email: '',
    password: ''
  });

  const { email, password } = formData;

  const onChange = e => setFormData({
    ...formData, [e.target.name]:e.target.value
  });

  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(loginUser({email, password}))
  }

  return (
    <div className="form-container">
      <form action="" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className="field-container">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" value={email} onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
        </div>
        <div className="field-container">
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="" value={password} onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
        </div>
        <button className='btn-submit' type="submit">Sign Up</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

I tried passing `{ rejectWithValue }` as also `thunkAPI` for then trying `thunkAPI.rejectWithValue` but still the same issue.

I am having the same issue when registering a user. Register comes fulfilled but loaduser rejected.
Why is this happening?

A util function for the token:

setAuthToken.js:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

const setAuthToken = token => {
  if (token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token'] = token;
  } else {
    delete axios.defaults.headers.common['x-atuh-token'];
  }
}

export default setAuthToken
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thunkAPI` is the ***second*** argument passed to the thunk function. See [Payload Creator](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator). The payload creator function takes up-to 2 arguments, the arg object passed to the thunk, and the `thunkAPI` that is passed from RTK.

It's a common convention to "name" unused/undefined/"throw away" args as `"_"`, but any valid Javascript identifier will work.

```js
export const loadUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/loadUser',
  async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }

    try {
      const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/me');
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);
```